# How we use the Query string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails programming, so please any one describe me what is meant by the **Query String** at what situation it is used for?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given "a query string is the part of a uniform resource locator (URL) that contains data to be passed to web applications such as CGI programs." from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You will find that rails is atypical for most query strings.  But, will also use typical query strings for some things.

Rails uses a routes file, which tells it what part of the url is a query string and what to match the field to.  A typical route may look something like `get "/posts/:id=>Post#show"`  When the user uses this route his URL would be `/posts/1` which would match id with 1 in the params hash.  This is generally used to pull content out of the rails model with that primary key and use the data to generate dynamic content.

Rails also gives you the ability to use the typical query string that is preceded by a question mark.  This has several applications.  One example could be a search query.  Any values in this are given to the params hash where the first piece preceding the equals sign is the field name and  the value assigned to that field is found after the equals sign.  Each field value is separated by an ampersand.

Comment: thanks for giving idea pessetto